# Template and URL parameter problem

Tags: templates

I have a template that lists posts by categories. It works great with the exception of categories with a space in their name.

I simply want to use a URL parameter to select the category and it only works if there is no space.  Adding a %20 doesn't help.

It works great when the category is a single word but doesn't work when the category has a space.  When I try to call it like this "https://url/?template=oneword" it's fine, when I try to call it with https://url/?firstword%20secondword" it's no good.

Using the slug doesn't work either; single word categories are fine and multi-word categories are blank (even though the slug is a single word).

Here's the template code I'm using:

```
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'parent' => 0,
'name' => $category_name
);

$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach  ($categories as $category) {
echo '<h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>';
echo '<ul>';

foreach (get_posts('cat='.$category->term_id) as $post) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';   
}  
echo '</ul>';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it's better to use slugs in URL. then the request is `$args = [
 'orderby' => 'name',
 'parent' => 0,
 'slug' => $_GET["template"]
];` and the URL looks like `server/?template=first-word-second-word`.

Comment: Is $category_name the URL parameter value? if so, have you tried running the value first through urldecode() ?